# Why does my SelectionSort not always work?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, selection

I'm a beginner and I'm now trying for the second day to implement SelectionSort for practicing purposes.
The algorithm I have works most of the times but not always. Unfortunatly it is totally unclear to me, why it does not always work.
The example is one were it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* selectionSort(int a_count, int *a);

int main(void)
{
    int a[] =     {4,2,3,4,4,9,98,98,3,3,3,4,2,98,1,98,98,1,1,4,98,2,98,3,9,9,3,1,4,1,98,9,9,2,9,4,2,2,9,98,4,98,1,3,4,9,1,98,98,4,2,3,98,98,1,99,9,98,98,3,98,98,4,98,2,98,4,2,1,1,9,2,4};
    int i, a_count = 73;
    int *result = selectionSort(a_count, a);
        for(i = 0; i < a_count; i++){
            printf("%i ", result[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}   

int* selectionSort(int a_count, int* a) {
    int i, j, min = 0, tmp;
    for(i = 0; i < a_count - 1; i++){
        min = i;
        printf("min_i = %i\n", min);
        for(j = i + 1; j < a_count; j++){
            printf("j = %i ", j);
                if(a[j] < a[min]){
                printf("%i < %i\n", a[j], a[min]);
                printf("min is changed: ");
                min = j;
                printf("min_j = %i\n", min);
            }
            tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[min];
            a[min] = tmp;
        }
   }
   return a;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is it always the same result for the same data? Or does one data set not always work?

Comment: @WeatherVane It seems to be always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are swapping element `i` with element `min` on every iteration of your loop over `j`.  This is both incorrect and inefficient.  Perform the swap after the inner loop finishes, so that `min` in fact contains the index of the minimum value of the current sub-array, not while you're still trying to figure out where that element is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple error, which is that you are not waiting until the end of the inner loop to do the swap.

```
int* selectionSort(int a_count, int* a) {
    int i, j, min = 0, tmp;
    for(i = 0; i < a_count - 1; i++){
        min = i;
        printf("min_i = %i\n", min);
        for(j = i + 1; j < a_count; j++){
            printf("j = %i ", j);
                if(a[j] < a[min]){
                printf("%i < %i\n", a[j], a[min]);
                printf("min is changed: ");
                min = j;
                printf("min_j = %i\n", min);
            }
        }
        tmp = a[i];         //  three lines moved out of the loop
        a[i] = a[min];      //
        a[min] = tmp;       //
   }
   return a;
}
```

Now the output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops, in the outer loop, you set min first, then in the inner loop, the min changed, which messed up the min value, and make your swap code wrong.
You can remove all code about min, use i, j directly, then should work.
change
if(a[j] < a[min])
to 
if(a[j] < a[i])

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class SelectionSort
{
    static int min;
    public static void Sort(int[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                min = j;
                if (data[i] < data[j])
                    Swap(x: ref data[i], y: ref data[min]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Swap(ref int x, ref int y)
    {
        int temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give a bit of explanation?